# Windows PowerShell equivalent to Unix/Linux `pwd`?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, powershell

In follow-up to the [cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921741/windows-equivilent-to-unix-pwd) question, what is the PowerShell equivalent to `echo %cd%`, or Linux/Unix `pwd`?

Comment: in cmd just `cd` is enough. no need to `echo %cd%`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

PowerShell has many of the same commands as Linux. `pwd` is the command equivalent.

When you type `pwd` in Powershell, it is an alias to `Get-Location`.

Comment: "that was easy" .. boy do I feel sheepish :)

Comment: Not exactly, Use `Get-Location | Foreach-Object { $_.Path }` to get only the path as in Linux pwd

Answer (score 31):

In addition to `Get-Location` and its Aliases, you can also use the automatic variable `$pwd`.

The `$pwd` variable is nice because you have direct access to the PathInfo members. E.g.

```
$pwd.Path.PadLeft(80)
$pwd.Drive
```

And if you ever want to know what members there are you can just pipe the command\alias to `Get-Member` :

```
PS C:\Users\your-name-here\Desktop> pwd|Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PathInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
ToString     Method     string ToString()
Drive        Property   System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo Drive {get;}
Path         Property   System.String Path {get;}
Provider     Property   System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo Provider {get;}
ProviderPath Property   System.String ProviderPath {get;}
```

Comment: very cool! I need to find a good tutorial introduction to PowerShell

Comment: Hover over the Powershell tag in your question. Click the FAQ link. Look at the second item in the list.

Answer (score 7):

It's `pwd`. You can "stringify" it by putting it in the quotes. More so, you can build up paths like so: `"$pwd\bin"`.

Comment: elegent,helpful,good.

Answer (score 4):

`Get-Location` cmdlet should do the trick

As Thiago mentioned, you can use these aliases: `gl` or `pwd`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the Path as Text without the usual header:
`(gl).Path  /*` is a short form for `Get-Location` with the object `Path`,
or `(pwd).Path`

Comment: Hi Peter and welcome to SU! when indicating stuff that should be typed, use \`backticks\` (usually the top left corner of QWERTY keyboards below `Esc`) to put it in code formatting (or for long blocks, indent every line by four spaces) to improve legibility :)